# Does installing packages in googleColab acts like virtual environment?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tesseract, python-tesseract, virtual-environment

I was wondering when you install packages such as tesseract in google colab, is it going to install it just for that notebook or folder and creates something like a virtual environment or its global to my gmail account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only installed to that instance which can only last for max 12 hours. After that, the instance is destroyed and you have to recreate it. You will have to install your packages again. You will not affect your Google account. Each instance is it’s own temporary environment.

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html